# Method of finding Arc length parameterization of a 3d curve

Tags: calculus, 3d, algebraic-curves

r(t) = cos^3 t i + sin^3 t j; 0 < t < pi/2.

r'(t) = -3cos^2 t sin t + 3 sin^2 t cos t

||r'(t)|| = 3 sin t cos t

Now to find the arc length parameterization, we need S = integration from t0 to t of ||dr/du|| du.

**Question: What is S here?**

Which gives 3/2 sin^2 t.

**After finding that, the book writes these stuff:**

[image]

What do these things mean?

Answer (score 1):

To find the arc length parameterization of a 3d curve, you should follow the following steps:

1) Find the arc length function

2) Solve for the function in step 1 for $t$

3) Replace $t$ with what you found in step 2

The arc length function is $$s(t) = \int_0^t |r'(u)|\hspace{1mm}du$$

$$s(t) = \int_0^t 3\sin u\cos u\hspace{1mm}du$$

$$s = \bigg[ \dfrac{3}{2}\sin^2 u\bigg]_0^t$$

$$s =  \dfrac{3}{2}\sin^2 t$$

Going into step 2: Now we solve for $t$

$$  \dfrac{2s}{3}=\sin^2 t$$

Take square root

$$  \sqrt{\dfrac{2s}{3}}=\sin t$$

$$  \arcsin\sqrt{\dfrac{2s}{3}}= t$$

Step 3: Substitute this in the given parametrization

$$r(s) = \left(\sqrt{1-\dfrac{2s}{3}}\right)^3i+\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2s}{3}}\right)^3j$$

Comment: In which equation do I plug the value of t in the second last line?

Comment: in the given parameterization, I did not show the steps of simplification

Comment: did you just plug the values of t in the original equation? [r(t)]?

Comment: yes, that's what I did